# Does java socket read the data exactly as it's sent

Tags: java, sockets

Consider we have a socket connection between two device (A and B). Now if I write only 16 bytes (size doesn't matter here) to the output stream (not BufferedOutputStream) of the socket in side A 3 times or in general more than once like this:

```
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
OutputStream.write(buffer);
OutputStream.write(buffer);
OutputStream.write(buffer);
```

I read the data in side B using the socket input stream (not BufferedInputStream) with a buffer larger than sending buffer for example 1024:

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = inputStream.read(buffer);
```

Now I wonder how the data is received on side B? May it get accumulated or it exactly read the data as A sends it? In another word may the read variable get more than 16?

Comment: It all depends on time. If B has received all of the input by the time it tries to read it, then it will read all 16*3 bytes. But if only one or two of them have been sent by that time, it will only read those.

Comment: How about If reading starts before sending? @Jon

Comment: @Ali: This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Ali I'd recommend reading the [Oracle Tutorial on I/O Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html) to get a better idea of how they actually work internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputStream` makes very few guarantees about how much data will be read by any invocation of the multi-byte `read()` methods.  There is a whole class of common programming errors that revolve around misunderstandings and wrong assumptions about that.  For example,

- if `InputStream.read(byte[])` reads fewer bytes than the provided array can hold, that does *not* imply that the end of the stream has been reached, or even that another read will necessarily block.
- the number of bytes read by any one invocation of `InputStream.read(byte[])` does not necessarily correlate to any characteristic of the byte source on which the stream draws, except that it will always read at least one byte when not at the end of the stream, and that it will not read more bytes than are actually available by the time it returns.
- the number of available bytes indicated by the `available()` method does not reliably indicate how many bytes a subsequent read should or will read.  A nonzero return value reliably indicates only that the next read will not block; a zero return value tells you *nothing at all*.

Subclasses may make guarantees about some of those behaviors, but most do not, and anyway you often do not know which subclass you actually have.

In order to use `InputStream`s properly, you generally must be prepared to perform repeated reads until you get sufficient data to process.  That can mean reading until you have accumulated a specific number of bytes, or reading until a delimiter is encountered.  In some cases you can handle any number of bytes from any given read; generally these are cases where you are looping anyway, and feeding everything you read to a consumer that can accept variable length chunks (many compression and encryption interfaces are like that, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs:

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes
>   actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until
>   input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is
>   thrown. If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is
>   returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If
>   no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the
>   value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored
>   into b.
>
> The first byte read is stored into element b[0], the next one into
>   b[1], and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to the
>   length of b. Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes
>   will be stored in elements b[0] through b[k-1], **leaving elements b[k]
>   through b[b.length-1] unaffected**.

`Read(...)` tells you how many bytes it put into the array and yes, you can read further; you'll get whatever was already there.